# Creating a looping background animation in jquery

Tags: jquery, animation, recurring

What I want is:

when the page loads - the background has color red
after 10 seconds the bgColor changes to green with a fade in fade out animation...
after another 10 seconds it changes to orange....then again to red and so on..

Could someone help

Comment: After reading your description I'm not sure I want to help anyone create such an abomination! ;)

Comment: its something similar to what i plan on doing.......check out pandora.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [setinterval](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) with a callback that changes the background:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    var colours = [ "blue", "orange", "pink" ];
    var counter = 0;
    function cycleBackground() {
        $("body").animate({ backgroundColor: colours[counter] }, 500 );
        counter++;
        if(counter == colours.length) {
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
    setInterval(cycleBackground, 10000);
});
```

You will need to use jQuery UI's [animate](http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/) function if you want to smoothly cycle between colors.

Comment: Add the fade animation and this is exactly right. (    `$("body").animate({ "background-color": colours[counter] });` if you include the jquery color animation plugin)

Comment: Thanks Joel, I initially missed the 'fadeIn' and 'fadeOut' bit. I think jQuery UI's animate can do colours.